# Is there any chances to put in a class the results obtained from an SQWRL query?

Tags: ontology, protege, swrl, sqwrl

I need to add, in an empty class, individuals obtained from an sqwrl query.
This is possible with an swrl rule but I can't do that with sqwrl.

Is there any chances to put in a class the results obtained from an SQWRL query?

For example in this image I have this result:
[image]

How can i put in a class the column v?
Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SQWRL#Semantics_of_SQWRLquery says "results cannot be written back to the ontology."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and sorry for my bad english.
I read that page and i missed it.